# Pandas.ExcelWriter() file corruption unless use .save() function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to use Pandas to write a dataframe to Excel. The data is just some price data from a public Crypto API:

[image: first few rows of data in Excel]

My code is as follows:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('crypto.xlsx')

btc.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Bitcoin') # btc = dataframe
```

This code produces a corrupt .xlsx file. I have found that I can produce a working one if I add the following to the end of the code:

```
writer.save()
```

However, adding this line gives this warning:

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1504\1045303506.py:7:
> FutureWarning: save is not part of the public API, usage can give
> unexpected results and will be removed in a future version
> writer.save()

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

> The writer should be used as a context manager. Otherwise, call `close()` to save and close any opened file handles.

So usually you will want to use `with` (writer needs to know when writing is finished so it flushes everything to disk, and you might want to write multiple sheets for example):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('crypto.xlsx') as writer:
    btc.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Bitcoin')
```

So you don't need to call `close` manually (which is [*synonym for `save`, to make it more file-like*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.close.html)).

P.S.

[`save`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.save.html) is depricated.